# Poblar de datos un Super - DataGrid

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

Trabajo en una app `Windows Forms`, `Entity Framework - code first`, `SQL Server 2019 Express Edition`, `Devcomponents`.

Trabajo con un `Super DataGrid`, que muestra Customers, Orders y Order Details el muestra filas despegables por medio de un `[+]`

[image: SuperDataGrid DevComponents]

En la documentación lo pueblan de datos con un `DataSet`pero este objeto tiene la particularidad de agregar relaciones.

```
private void BindCustomerData()
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Resources";

        if (location != null)
        {
            _DataSet = new DataSet();

            string path = Path.Combine(location, "nwind.mdb");

            using (OleDbConnection cn =
                new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
                    + path + ";User Id=admin;Password=;"))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers;", cn);
                adapter.Fill(_DataSet, "Customers");

                new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders;", cn).Fill(_DataSet, "Orders");
                new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order Details];", cn).Fill(_DataSet, "Order Details");

                _DataSet.Relations.Add("1", _DataSet.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
                                       _DataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"], false);

                _DataSet.Relations.Add("2", _DataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["OrderID"],
                                       _DataSet.Tables["Order Details"].Columns["OrderID"], false);
            }

            superGridControl1.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = _DataSet;
            superGridControl1.PrimaryGrid.DataMember = "Customers";
        }
    }
```

**¿Como lo podría hacer con listas?** `List<>` el mismo código.

He podido cargar datos de la siguiente manera pero no de forma anidada.

Acceso a datos

```
public IEnumerable<CustomerExtend> BindCustomerData()
    {

        using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
        {
            var query = from c in context.Customers
                        .Include("Orders")
                        select new CustomerExtend()
                        {
                            CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                            CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                            ContactName = c.ContactName,
                            Orders = c.Orders
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Presentación

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sgPrueba.PrimaryGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        sgPrueba.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = _customerRepository.ListaCustomer().ToList();

    }
```

El problema es la navegabilidad hay navegabilidad de Customer a Orden y de Orden a Orden Detail

[image: Maestro detalle]

Me falta indicar por código navegar de Order a Order Detail

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
public DataSet AllCustomer()
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection cn = context.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers;", cn);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Customers");

            new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Orders;", cn).Fill(dataSet, "Orders");
            new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Order Details];", cn).Fill(dataSet, "Order Details");

            dataSet.Relations.Add("1", dataSet.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
                                   dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"], false);

            dataSet.Relations.Add("2", dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["OrderID"],
                                   dataSet.Tables["Order Details"].Columns["OrderID"], false);

            return dataSet;
        }
    }
```